# How to swap the first word with the last word in the file in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to move the first word to the last position in Java.What could I be missing?
Doesn't change the first word to the last one and is not sure that then the String is added to the file again.

```
public class WorkString {

    public WorkString() {
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    public void swapWords() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Enter file name : ");
        filename = reader.readLine();
        fio = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filename), "r");
        data = fio.readLine();
        System.out.println("Information from file : " + data);
        String content = fio.toString();
        System.out.println(content);
        String[] ori = content.split(" ");
        String str = "";
        String temp=ori[0];
        ori[0]=ori[ori.length-1];
        ori[ori.length-1]=temp;   

        for(int i = 1; i < ori.length; i++)
            str += ori[i];

        fio.writeBytes(str + ori[0]); // Can I do this?
        fio.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change the first word with the last

Comment: `String str = content.substring(content.indexOf(" ")).concat(content.substring(0, content.indexOf(" ")));`

Comment: Does this help? http://javabyhapi.blogspot.com/2016/08/java-program-to-swap-first-and-last.html

Comment: The `"r"` is for read, not read and write. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question and post the entire text of the assignment you have been given, because it is unclear what, exactly you need to do. Do you need to replace the text in the file? Do you need to append text to the file? Do you just need to read from the file? Do you have to use `RandomAccessFile`? By the way, it may be easier to use [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for getting input from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void swapWords() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Enter file name : ");
    String filename = reader.readLine();
    RandomAccessFile fio = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filename), "rw");
    String data = fio.readLine();
    
    System.out.println("Information from file : " + data);
    String content = data;
    System.out.println(content);
    String[] ori = content.split(" ");
    String str = "";
    String temp=ori[0];
    ori[0]=ori[ori.length-1];
    ori[ori.length-1]=temp;  
    
    str = String.join(" ", ori);

    fio.write(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    fio.close();
}
```

Comment: ```    String.join(" ", ori);
        fio.writeChars(str);
        String ndata = fio.readLine();
        System.out.println(ndata); ```  outputs is null

Comment: I've edited the answer and put your example modified.

Comment: everything works except swap the first and last word

Comment: Are you sure? Testing here on a file with content of "word1 word2 word3" will change the file's content to "word1 word2 word3word3 word2 word1". However, if you are evaluating the result based on system.out, you should execute "System.out.println(str);" at the end, after "fio.close()", for instance.